# How to get wordpress repeater field data without using have_rows()

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to get ACF repeater field data using default WordPress query like get_post_meta()

and I don't know how to get this using WordPress functions when I try to use get_post_meta() it will give me only loop count.

I need this becuse have_rows increase my server response time and that's why I think default WordPress functions is better to use

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to get the have_rows() then you will have to do following:

```
$total_number_of_rows = get_post_meta($post_id, 'yourmetakey', true);
```

So you will get the total numbers, now you can set the for loop for that like below

```
for( $i = 0; $i < $total_number_of_rows; $i++ ) {
    $get_sub_field1 = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'yourmetakey_' . $i . '_subkeyname1', true );
    $get_sub_field2 = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'yourmetakey_' . $i . '_subkeyname2', true );
}
```

Comment: Hello, Pixlogix thanks for your response now you are second time helping me thanks a lot for this. if this work I will really appreciate.

Comment: Hey Pixlogix you rock thanks a lot this helps me a lot and if you know how to get post thumbnail can you please help me for this as well thanks in advance